# Very confused! Past Participles As Adjectives or Passive Voice express a routine or an on-going task

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

We all know that simple present tense shows Repeated Actions such as a habit, a hobby, a daily event, a scheduled event or something that often happens ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Eg: *I play tennis.*

We also know that Non-Continuous Verbs or Stative verbs used in Simple Present to express an action is happening or is not happening now ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Ex: *I am here now* = *I am staying here now*.

It is wrong to say "*I am being here now*".

Now, let see this sentence:

*He breaks TVs* (a regular event)

Eg: *I dress in a black suit* ("dress" is a normal verb, so this sentence shows a habit / regular event)

and their passive forms:

*TVs are broken by him* (a regular event)

*I am dressed in a black suit* (a habit / regular event)

But, we also have "broken as an adjective ([Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/broken?q=broken))"

Eg: *a broke leg*

Eg: *TVs are broken*. So the to be (**are**) in this case expresses a fact or a regular action?

we've also got the adjective "**[dressed](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dressed?q=dressed)**"

Eg: *I am dressed in a black suit*: the verb **to be** here expresses an on-going action (that is happening now) or a regular event?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: "I am dressed in a black suit" means at this moment, not a regular event. "Can I wear a gray tie? I am dressed in a black suit." "Yes, but blue would bring out your eyes for the interview."

Comment: The various forms of "be" express a condition in the associated time frame, they don't express habitual activity.  Only simple present is habitual.  "I dress in black": habitual activity.  "I dressed for dinner":  a specific event (past tense verb).  "I am dressed": present condition = dressed (adjective).

Answer (score 1):

Tom, you’re missing too much. Please look at English Language Learners.

*I am here now* doesn’t equal *I am staying here now*.

It is wrong to say *I am being here now* except, just possibly, in Indian English.

*He breaks TVs* does describe a regular event, as would *I dress in black*. Because you added so much detail, your sentence showed not habit but confusion.

*TVs are broken by him* might grammatically be a regular event; semantically, it’s confusing at best; in all likelihood, silly.

*I am dressed in a black suit* describes what I’m wearing now; no question of habit.

We do not have *a broke leg*, do we? How would *A broken leg* help, here?

*So the to be (are) in this case* expresses your confusion, not a fact or regular action.

As it did above, *I am dressed in a black suit* expresses neither a continuous (your *on-going*) action nor a regular event. It describes what you are wearing now. That you will prolly be wearing the same thing five seconds, five minutes or even five hours from now is purely logical; nothing to do with grammar.

For a continuous or habitual action you would have used not *I am dressed in* but *I dress in*…

Comment: Maybe, I chose the wrong word "*to stay*", but that is not the main part of my expression. I mean "I am here now" expresses the action that is happening now. That is my main intention. http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html

Comment: "I am dressed in a black suit" means that wearing action is happening.  http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html

Comment: Tom, please note *to stay* is not a word. *to stay* is not found in your question.

Check any dictionary to prove *my expression* doesn’t fit the context

You might well have *meant* that *I am here now expressed the action that is happening now* and if you think that’s a reasonable interpretation of the text you posted, please explain how.

Comment: *I am dressed in a black suit* could mean *wearing action was happening* only if English recognised the form, * wearing action was happening*. It doesn’t.

Will you please take your question to ELL?

Comment: I provided the link: englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html. "*I am here now*" may express "*the action that is happening now*". The same thing applies to "*I am dressed in a black suit*" which may express "*the action is happening now*"

Comment: That ice is thin, Tom… in text books, Present Simple says an action is happening now. That’s not a comprehensive description; it doesn’t support paraphrasing like *I am here now expresses the action that is happening now.*

You started with *I am dressed in black… (a habit / regular event)*; now, that might express *action happening now*?

I am here now can’t equate to I am staying here now partly because *I am here now* doesn’t express an action; it describes a combination of a location and a state of being which exists now.

How many hours d’you think we have, in which to go sideways?